# Current amplifier concept in solar panel

Tags: led, batteries, current, amplifier

Whether the output of the solar panel is given to a current amplifier to increase the ampere rating? So that we can increase the ampere hour rating of the battery which will be connected to the solar panel.

Comment: Please edit (otherwise this question will be closed): What are you asking about (it doesn't make sense)? Also, please use proper case/capitalization. It's rude in the Internet to type all letters as capitalized for it represents shouting.

Comment: Huh? *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.*

Comment: @Olin - agreed, looks like there isn't much hope for this one, voting to close now as there has been no update/clarification to the question. Happy new year by the way ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Your question isn't entirely clear regarding what you are trying to do - I'll assume it's charge a battery with a solar panel.

If you increase the current output, the voltage must drop accordingly (conservation of energy - the overall power output must stay the same) Also, you can never increase the Ah capacity of the battery - this is fixed (well almost - it will degrade over time)
If you mean can you increase the charge time by charging at a higher current, then this is possible with a buck converter (e.g. lower the voltage, increase the current)

Solar panels have a I-V curve, and around the knee of that curve is the Maximum Power Point (MPPT) where the most power will be delivered to the load. There are ICs designed for the purpose of [Maximum Power Point Tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking) whist maintaining the desired battery charging profile, check on Mouser, Farnell, etc - Linear Tech and NXP make a few good ones IIRC (here are two examples, the [MPT612](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MPT612.pdf) and the [LT3652](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3652))
For example, let's say you have a 12V nominal 2A panel. You you have maximum current if you short the leads, but then you have no voltage, so 0V * 2A = 0W. Similarly, if you open the leads, you have maximum voltage but no current, i.e. 12V * 0A = 0W.

What you need is the MPPT mentioned above, where the product of the voltage and current is at it's highest. You can see this point in the below diagram.

[image: MPPT Example]